# Cannot connect to SQL Server Express from SSMS but can from VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssms, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. I have also installed SQL Server Management Studio. I cannot connect to my localhost\sqlexpress server using SSMS. However, I can connect via Visual Studio 2010. I can also connect to my SQL Azure database from within visual studio but cannot from SQL Server Management Studio.

Any help or direction would be great...

EDIT: I use the localhost\sqlexpress instance in Visual Studio 2010 through Server Explorer and it works fine. Basically it seems like an SSMS bug?

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Azure you need SQL Management Studio from 2008 R2 (earlier versions can't connect to azure).

For local connection you can also use `.` (dot) or `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

Answer (score 1):

What name are you using for servername? You need to use `Computer-Name\SQLEXPRESS` for the server name in the logon prompt.